# How to define range in For loop of 2d list, when rows are unknown?

Tags: python, list, for-loop

I need to have a For loop in a 2d list, except I would like the loop to keep going until the end of the file, when the length is unknown.

This is my code:

```
while sales_search == 'Y':
    columns = 13
    with open('sales.txt', 'rt', encoding = 'utf8') as inf:
        data = list(csv.reader(inf,skipinitialspace=True))
        data = [i for i in data if i]
    rows = 0
    for row in range(rows):
        for col in range(columns):
            if (columns==0):
                found = False
                print ('****************')
                search = input ('What year do you want to search for:')
                if year == search:
                    print ('****************')
                    print ('Year:', (data[row][0]))
                    print ('The amount made from the Toyota Klugers is $',
                           format((data[row][1]),',.2f'))
                    print ('The amount made from the Nissan Patrols is $', 
                           format((data[row][2]),',.2f'))
                    print ('The amount made from the Ford Territorys is $', 
                           format((data[row][3]),',.2f'))
                    print ('The total amount made from all three cars is $', 
                           format((data[row][4]),',.2f'))                
                    print ('The bonus amount is $', 
                           format((data[row][5]),',.2f'))
                    print ('The bonus contributed through the sale of the Toyota Klugers is $', 
                           format((data[row][6]),',.2f'))
                    print ('The bonus contributed through the sale of the Nisssan Patrols is $', 
                           format((data[row][7]),',.2f'))
                    print ('The bonus contributed through the sale of the Ford Territorys is $', 
                           format((data[row][8]),',.2f'))
                    print ('The additional bonus for the Toyota Kluger is $', 
                           format((data[row][9]),',.2f'))
                    print ('The additional bonus for the Nissan Patrol is $', 
                           format((data[row][10]),',.2f'))
                    print ('The additional bonus for the Ford Territory is $', 
                           format((data[row][11]),',.2f'))
                    print ('The total bonus is $', 
                           format((data[row][12]),',.2f'))
                    found = True
```

I would greatly appreciate if help could be given :)

Comment: What is happening now?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want

```
for row in data:
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just iterate over `data`. It is an array representing the lines of the file.

```
with open('sales.txt', 'rt', encoding = 'utf8') as inf:
    data = list(csv.reader(inf,skipinitialspace=True))
    data = [i for i in data if i]
for row in data:
    for col in row:
        # do something with each column

    # ...or, as you were doing before...
    print ('Year:', row[0])
    print ('...', row[1])
    # etc.
```

Answer (score 0):

Right now you are doing `for row in range(rows)`, which is `for row in range(0)`. This is effectively looping over an empty list.

```
>>> for row in range(0):
...     print row
... 
>>>
```

Instead, use `for row in data`, which will assign the row to an actual piece of data from your file:

```
while sales_search == 'Y':
            columns = 13
            with open('sales.txt', 'rt', encoding = 'utf8') as inf:
                data = list(csv.reader(inf,skipinitialspace=True))
                data = [i for i in data if i]
            rows = 0
            for row in data:
                for col in row:
                    #Do your stuff
                #Do your stuff
```

Comment: I followed these instructions & all I get is: 

'===========================================

Welcome to ABC Car Shop:

Please choose an option from the following:
A = Add sales details in the database.
S = Search sales details for a given year in the database.
Q = Quit.
Which option do you choose:S

===========================================
Do you want to search for another year (Y/N):'